# Executing stored procedures in oracle inside a package using dbms_job

Tags: oracle, jobs, oracle-9i

I am trying to execute multiple stored procedures through package using DBMS_JOB. Even if the job is getting submitted and is showing in USER_JOBS its not getting started for some reason. I have tried with and without putting the 'START DATE' parameter with the same result i.e. no start.

I am using ORACLE 9i and i guess i cannot use dbms_scheduler.

Find below the code :

```
--PACKAGE BODY--

create or replace
PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST IS

  PROCEDURE PASSPORT_DC_1 IS

  l_jobno binary_integer;
  l_jobno1 binary_integer;

    BEGIN

       dbms_job.submit(l_jobno1, 'BEGIN SP_ABC(); END;',SYSDATE );
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SP_UPDATE_TIDCUMTL :' || l_jobno1);
       COMMIT;

       dbms_job.submit(l_jobno, 'BEGIN SP_XYZ(); END;',SYSDATE);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SP_UPDATE_TIDPTDTL :' || l_jobno);
       COMMIT; 

  END PASSPORT_DC_1;

--PACKAGE SPEC--

create or replace PACKAGE PKG_TEST AS

  PROCEDURE PASSPORT_DC_1;

END PKG_TEST;
```

Comment: Its a while since I used 9i but have you tried the start_date as SYSDATE + 1/1440 ? Also check in DBA_JOBS for what Oracle believes has been set for the job and to check it isn't 'BROKEN'. Then try DBMS_JOB.RUN to force it to run. At least you'll know if its runnable.

Comment: Yeah try running the job immediately to see what the problem is. Also, Oracle 9 went out of support in 2006...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run the job now then don't add a date/time.
You can use this as a test case, run as an anonymous block to verify it works then modify your package.

```
DECLARE
l_jobno1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
dbms_job.submit(l_jobno1, 'SP_ABC();');
END;
```

You should definitely qualify the procedure name with the schema owner as in 
XYZ.sp_ABC()